# How can I edit a prior predictive search?

Tags: cyanogenmod, text-prediction, search-history, browser-history

When typing a URL into my Cyanogenmod phone's browser, as I type, it suggests URL(s) from prior browsing that match what I have typed, similarly, when on a Google web search page, if I begin to type in a search string, the phone offers prior searches that match what I have typed in thus far in a drop down list from which you can select.

This is a great feature, but sometimes, I want to take the prior history and modify it slightly or append to it.  This is especially common with a search where I want to add more words to my prior search.

Is there anyway to somehow select one of the suggestions without immediately invoking it and thus allowing me to edit it slightly before submission?